# Raise automatic moderator flag after several spam posts from same account or IP address

Tags: feature-request, spam, automatic-flags

I was rather irritated when reading [this answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4757/11875), by EL&U moderator:

> I'd suggest that when you see something like this, flag one of the posts with a custom flag to bring it to our attention

Sorry but I don't think that's correct. Spam should be flagged as spam, *period*.

I do understand the problem though, so my suggestion for a win-win solution is raise automatic moderator flag after X posts have been auto deleted as spam from same account or IP address.

Above example is from a specific site, but the idea holds true for all sites.

This won't stop spam of course, just make the spammers' life bit harder by having their accounts deleted faster.

Comment: Oops, my search skills failed me this time, this was asked already. ^^